# Is there any definition for #pragma location?

Tags: c, iar

I need an explanation on this piece of code !
I know a little about it but not enough

```
#if defined ( __ICCARM__ )
#pragma location="ExtQSPIFlashSection" 
#else
__attribute__((section(".ExtQSPIFlashSection")))
#endif
```

It's in IAR

Thank you anyway:)

Comment: What do you mean by definition of `pragma location`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#pragma` and `__attribute__(......` are just specific for the the particular compiler. With them you do exactly the same - place the object into the particular section in the memory. The sections are defined in the linker script

Comment: hi thanks for the answer where exactly can I see memory sections?

Comment: in your linker script https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/linker/how-do-i-place-a-group-of-functions-or-variables-in-a-specific-section/

Comment: where is my linker script in IAR?and what's the format?

Comment: @Alireza If you have some more questions that fit SO format, ask them as a question, not as a comment.The person who have answered this specific question does not necessarily know the answer to your other questions.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. in the link everything is explained. I am not going to guide how to find the file on the computer.

Comment: @PeterJ Thanks I will find that myself but how about ICCARM do you know anything about it?

Comment: @Alireza As I know google is still operational. And you need a bit C language - to understand the preprocesor, macros and anothe boring stuff